# How to read bytewise from stdin?

Tags: go, byte, buffer, stdin

```
in, out := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin), bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
for {
    c, err := in.ReadByte()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    out.WriteByte(c)
}
```

I want to read bytewise from the stdin stream. Unlike the `Read` method`ReadByte` doesn't seem to return `io.EOF`. How can I break if all bytes have been read?

Comment: `ReadByte reads and returns a single byte. If no byte is available, returns an error.` read until there is an error, then break. So `if err != nil { ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue of the [`Reader.ReadByte()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadByte) implementation, nor that of [`bufio.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader).

See this example to prove it:

```
buf := bytes.NewBufferString("Hello World!\n")
in := bufio.NewReader(buf)
for {
    c, err := in.ReadByte()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    fmt.Print(string(c))
}
```

When running, the above prints

```
Hello World!
```

And terminates properly.

Your issue is with `os.Stdin`. Reading from it is specific to its source. If it is your terminal, reading from it simply blocks and does not report `io.EOF`. See this example to prove it:

```
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
for {
    fmt.Println("Reading.")
    c, err := in.ReadByte()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    fmt.Print(string(c))
}
```

Its output is:

```
Reading.
```

And nothing happens. There is no new iteration, it is blocked. Now if you enter a line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, e.g. you enter `Go!`, output will be:

```
Go!
GReading.
oReading.
!Reading.

Reading.
```

And again, waits for new input. As you can see, data is fed / available per line. This is what your terminal does: while you enter your line, it is not sent to `os.Stdin`. Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the whole line is fed and is available from `os.Stdin`. This is what we see: each letter of the input `Go!` and a newline character. And we see the `Reading.` text printed for each iteration. After the input is consumed, `in.ReadByte()` is blocked again, waiting for new input. It does not report `io.EOF`.

Now try the following: create a file e.g. `a.txt` and edit it to have one line: `Go!` and a newline. Now feed this file as the standard input to your program:

```
go run play.go < a.txt
```

Running it we'll see:

```
Reading.
GReading.
oReading.
!Reading.

Reading.

Reading.
```

And it terminates so it works! It works because this time the source of `os.Stdin` is not your console / terminal, but the contents of a file, and once it's consumed, attempting to read from `os.Stdin` will properly report `io.EOF`.